# JwtAuthenticationToken is not mocked

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, jwt

hello I am working with spring boot, using jwt, the probleme is that I have two user names, the first is maped to Principal#getName and I use it for apis, the second comes with the claims and it used to access database, I mocked Principal but I still got 403 error instead of  200 ,here is an exmple of an api with no preathorize annotation :

```
@PostMapping("/predeclarations/{predeclaration}/peoples")
public PersonCreationDto addPerson(@PathVariable String predeclaration,
                                   @Valid @RequestBody PersonDto personDto,
                                   @RequestParam AccidentMemberEnum memberType,
                                   JwtAuthenticationToken principal){
    log.debug("Start api: adding person");
    var output = claimService.addPerson(JwtUtils.getAs400User(principal), predeclaration, personDto, memberType, false);
    log.debug("End api: adding person");
    return output;
}
```

here is the test :

```
@Test
void Should_Add_Person() throws Exception {
    //given
    var person = DataGenerator.person();
    var memberType = AccidentMemberEnum.INSURED;
    List<GrantedAuthority> updatedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
    updatedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(RoleTypeEnum.Fields.ROLE_AxaClaimsRoleDirector));
    var jwtAuthenticationToken = new JwtAuthenticationToken(mock(Jwt.class), updatedAuthorities, null);
    jwtAuthenticationToken.setDetails(Collections.singletonMap(GlobalConstants.AS400_USER_CLAIM, username));
    jwtAuthenticationToken.setAuthenticated(true);

    //when
    when(claimService.addPerson(username, PREDECLARATION_NUMBER, person, memberType, false)).thenReturn(DataGenerator.personCreationCaseOK());

    //then
    var customAuthentication = new CustomAuthentication(jwtAuthenticationToken);
    var json = ow.writeValueAsString(person);
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(BASE_URL + PREDECLARATION_NUMBER + "/peoples?memberType=INSURED")

                    .principal(customAuthentication)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(json))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

the security configuration :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${conf.security.enabled:true}")
    private boolean securityEnabled;

    @Value("${conf.security.allowed-origin:*}")
    private String allowedOriginPattern;
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri}")
    private String jwtSetUri;

    private static InnerRbacProxy rbacProxy;

    public SecurityConfig(InnerRbacProxy rbacProxy) {
        this.rbacProxy = rbacProxy;
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(jwtSetUri).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.cors()
                .and()
                .cors().and()
                .csrf().disable() //NOSONAR
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(securityAccessDeniedHandler())
                .authenticationEntryPoint(securityAuthEntryPoint());
        if (!securityEnabled) {
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        } else {
            http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests(authRequests -> {
                        // Permissions OPTIONS
                        authRequests.mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll();
                        // Management endpoints
                        authRequests.mvcMatchers("/management/**", "/docs/**", "/webjars/**").permitAll();
                        // Business APIs
                        authRequests.anyRequest().authenticated();
                    });
            http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter());
        }

        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder setPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        var corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("*"));

        var source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler securityAccessDeniedHandler() {
        return new SecurityAccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint securityAuthEntryPoint() {
        return new SecurityAuthEntryPoint();
    }

    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        var customAuthoritiesConverter = new CustomAuthoritiesConverter();
        var authenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        authenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(customAuthoritiesConverter);
        authenticationConverter.setPrincipalClaimName(GlobalConstants.DEFAULT_CLAIM);
        return authenticationConverter;
    }

    static class CustomAuthoritiesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {

        @Override
        public Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) {
            var roleDto = rbacProxy
                    .getRolesByUsername(jwt.getClaimAsString(GlobalConstants.DEFAULT_CLAIM), GlobalConstants.ORGANISATION);
            var permissionsDto = rbacProxy
                    .getUserPermissions(jwt.getClaimAsString(GlobalConstants.DEFAULT_CLAIM), GlobalConstants.ORGANISATION, GlobalConstants.APPLICATION);
            var roles = roleDto.stream()
                    .map(RoleDto::getCode).collect(Collectors.toList());
            var permissions = permissionsDto.isEmpty() ? new ArrayList<String>() : permissionsDto.get(0).getPermissions().stream()
                    .map(PermissionDto::getCode).collect(Collectors.toList());
            List<GrantedAuthority> updatedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
            roles.forEach(role -> updatedAuthorities
                    .add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(StringUtils.prefixWithRole(role))));
            permissions.forEach(permission -> updatedAuthorities
                    .add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(permission)));
            return updatedAuthorities;
        }
    }
}
```

and the CustomAuthentication :

```
public class CustomAuthentication implements Authentication {

    private final JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuthenticationToken;

    public CustomAuthentication(JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuthenticationToken) {
        this.jwtAuthenticationToken = jwtAuthenticationToken;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return jwtAuthenticationToken.getAuthorities();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return jwtAuthenticationToken.getCredentials();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getDetails() {
        return jwtAuthenticationToken.getDetails();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return jwtAuthenticationToken.getPrincipal();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return jwtAuthenticationToken.isAuthenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthenticated(boolean isAuthenticated) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        jwtAuthenticationToken.setAuthenticated(isAuthenticated);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return jwtAuthenticationToken.getName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just came across the same issue you're having: trying to mock the user principal for tests.
And that's what I did

```
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtClaimNames;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.RequestPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;


import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import(UserServiceManagementController.class) // <=== add your controller class here
class ScratchTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateUserWithNoRequiredProperties() throws Exception {
        var person = DataGenerator.person();
        var memberType = AccidentMemberEnum.INSURED;
        List<GrantedAuthority> updatedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        updatedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(RoleTypeEnum.Fields.ROLE_AxaClaimsRoleDirector));



        //when
        when(claimService.addPerson(username, PREDECLARATION_NUMBER, person, memberType, false)).thenReturn(DataGenerator.personCreationCaseOK());

        Jwt.Builder jwtBuilder = Jwt.withTokenValue("token").header("alg", "none")
                .claim(JwtClaimNames.SUB, "user") // <=== add your user here
                .issuer("https://issuer-host/auth/realms/RealmOfJesus")
                .claim("scope", "read");

        var jwt = jwtBuilder.build();
        //then
        mockMvc.perform(post(BASE_URL + PREDECLARATION_NUMBER + "/peoples?memberType=INSURED")
                        .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt().jwt(jwt)) 
                        .principal(customAuthentication)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(json))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

I've tried to clean up the configuration the most I could, in my case I also needed to create a new implementation of this `jwt()` to produce an specific implementation of `JwtAuthenticationToken`. In your case, all you need to do is call the method.

Hope it helps for what it's worth.